# How do I create a chat room

Tags: support, chat

The title says it, how do I create a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com)? (specifically, it's for discussion about a programming language I made)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) page on your site, you'll see that you need 100 reputation points to create a new chat room.*

So, you'll need to participate and gain some reputation before you can do this.

Before doing so, it might be an idea to join the standard chatroom on your site, participate for a while and ask there whether there's any interest in your subject - it would probably be quite lonely for you to be there without any other participants...

From the help page:

> **When should I create a new chat room?**
>
> When you find yourself wanting to have an extended conversation about a topic that is not covered by one of the existing chat rooms, you should create a new room for it.
>
> **How do I create a new chat room?**
>
> There is a link to chat in the footer of every page. The link also appears in the Stack Exchange site switcher on the upper right corner of every page. Click one of those links, and then click the "create a new room" button at the bottom of the Rooms page.
>
> **What happens when I create a new room?**
>
> After you create the room, you'll want to invite other users into your room -- either using the invite room menu option, or by pasting the URL to your room as a chat message in other rooms you're participating in.
>
> You can share the chat room URL with the broader internet, but bear in mind that only users who hold the chat privilege on the parent site will be able to talk in your room!
>
> **What other new privileges in chat do I get?**
>
> At 100 reputation you also get access to the "Upload image" button in chat.

- It really will be a great idea to look around the rest of the help pages while you're there.  There's a lot there that you'll find very helpful.

Comment: I used your links but neither seemed to be what you were describing.

Might it matter that they linked to different pages?

The bottom Link led to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat

The upper right link led to https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=meta.stackexchange.com

Neither had anything like a ‘create a new room’ button.

The first did not contain the word ‘rooms’.

The second had a ‘Rooms’ label under its ‘Meta’ icon and nothing else apparently relevant.

Have things changed 2018; am I simply missing something or what, please?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. You'll need [100 reputation](/help/privileges/chat-rooms) to create a chatroom.

Note that this 100 reputation can be earned on separate sites together, but Meta Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow have their own chat server so to create a chat room on either of those, you'll have to earn 100 on the individual site.